# UITextView attributedText changingfont size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have some UItextView IBOutlet, I need set attributed string in them. In code I have:

```
NSArray *textViews = @[self.addressTextView, self.webpageTextView, self.phoneTextView, self.phone2TextView, self.emailTextView, self.emailPkTextVIew, self.akkrTextView, self.licenseTxt];
...
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < textViews.count; i++) {
    UITextView *txtView = textViews[i]; 
    ... //making attributed string
    NSMutableAttributedString *fullString;
    ...
    [fullString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0] range:(NSRange){0,fullString.length}];
    NSLog(@"\n%@", fullString);
    txtView.attributedText = fullString;
    NSLog(@"\n%@ %@", txtView.attributedText);
}
```

So in first log I see that font-size is 15, but in second case sometimes all good (for text view), but sometimes font-size become 22 or 25. Why?

[image]

Comment: check your font size of each textview in xib.

Comment: @Madhumitha it is no matter what font size have UITextView^ because it is attributedString

Comment: Besides what `NSLog` is displaying, is there an issue?

Comment: I have the same problem and still no solution.